# HTML Scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to search

```
<span>Status:</span>,
  <span><strong>Moored</strong></span>,
  <strong>Moored</strong
```

And pull out `Moored`. I've tried a lot of things but haven't been able to get it. Most recently `find(attrs={'span':'Status:'})` but that just returns `[]`. There are a lot of things tagged with `<strong>` in the HTML, but this is the only `<strong>` after a `<span>Status:`

Edit: the HTML snipped above is a result of running
`a = soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'vertical-offset-10 group-ib'})` then iterating over each loop with `a = (row.findChildren())`

In the HTML:

```
<div class="vertical-offset-10 group-ib">
                    <span>Status:</span>
                    <span><strong>Moored</strong></span>
                </div>
```

To clarify, all I want is the string `Moored`

Comment: I can convert an HTML search from english ("show me every span tag who's third child is a strong tag with text AND the text starts with a capital letter") but your post doesn't have that - what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I want to search the `<span>` tags for `Status` and pull out the `<strong>` text thereafter.

Comment: Got it, possible answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = soup.find_all('span', text="Status:")
res[0].parent.find('strong').text
```

soup.find_all searches for all `<span>` tags that contain the text `"Result:"`, then takes the next_sibling (the next `<span>` tag) and gets that tag's text contents.

Comment: for some reason this didn't work for me. the `next_sibling` command just returned an empty array. I had to do `res[0].parent.find('strong').text` Thanks for the help! If you want to edit your answer, I'll be happy to accept it. I

Comment: Probably due to sloppy copy & pasting on my part. I update my answer!